# Haskell -- main.hs:121:19: parse error on input `<-'

Tags: file, parsing, haskell, line, program-entry-point

```
import System.Environment
import Control.Monad

getLines = liftM lines . readFile

main = do
    argv <- getArgs
    name <- getProgName
    if not (null argv)
    then let file = head argv 
             list <- getLines file
             mapM_ putStrLn list
    else hPutStr stderr $ "usage: " ++ name ++ " number\n"
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `let` block should be followed either by more 'variable' assignments, or should be ended. In that case, you want to align the next actions under the `let`. All of this should be in a `do` statement.

So.... You want to have a `do` right after your `then`, and you want to align the `list <- ...` and `mapM_ ...` with the let command:

```
main = do
    argv <- getArgs
    name <- getProgName
    if not (null argv)
    then do
       let file = head argv 
       list <- getLines file
       mapM_ putStrLn list
    else hPutStr stderr $ "usage: " ++ name ++ " number\n"
```

Comment: thanks, i'm new to Haskell, but this method seem like a good standard way to work with files or is there a more preferred  way?

Comment: Always depends on your usage. Are you asking if it's idiomatic? Not necessarily but that shouldn't matter.

Work with what you have now, and when you start becoming more advanced you'll end up refactoring it. Don't worry about it now if it works.